# How to run an exe in linux?

Tags: c++, elf, portable-executable

suppose I have a .exe file and i want it to run in Linux without using wine tool.

i want to convert PE->ELF.

can anyone help how to programatically do this?

Thanks,
Sujitha.kv

Comment: If you can figure this out, you will be a very rich man...

Comment: Even if there is some tool that converts a PE to an ELF file it's not going to work as the file will still call the Windows APIs.

Comment: This isn't possible, the platforms are binary incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible cause it's a totally different OS!

the only way is to make it run through a program like Wine

Comment: Operating system, not necessarily architecture.

Comment: Wine is not an emulator, it's a compatibility layer. Meaning it doesn't emulate/use a VM, it translates windows API calls into POSIX api calls.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially need to strip all the interesting code parts from the EXE, but none of the PE specific information and then re-assemble and re-link the code into an ELF file. This will require some reverse engineering and a lot of manual work.

This would be very difficult, so I suggest you simply use WINE.